# How to give a linebreak in Python writing to a file in UTF-16 BE?

Tags: python, python-3.x, line-breaks

I am trying to get data from a list of files and paste it into a single text file called `list.txt`

```
arab_name = ""

for i in range (len(txts)):
    with open('C:\\Users\\Malik\\Desktop\\ARABIC_WORDS\\Animals\\' + txts[i]) as f:
        s = f.read()
        arab_name += s + '\n'

f = open("list.txt", "x")
f.write(arab_name)
```

The resulting text file has strange characters show up in the text file instead of a line break?
`arab_name += s + '\n'`
How do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: Have you inspected the variable ```arab_name``` before writing it to the ```list.txt```. When you open a file, the Python use the ```locale.getpreferredencoding()``` encoding to translate byte code into unicode. In my case the function returns ```cp1252``` which may or may not translate UTF-16 text properly. Also with ```open("list.txt", "x")```, in my case it created a utf-8 (no BOM) file not UTF-16 BE file.

Comment: I gets the correct encoding. And it creates a utf16 be file. That is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You prob need to specify utf-8.. try this:

```
f = open("list.txt", "x", encoding="UTF-8")
```

another option is to do the encoding on the variable itself:

```
arab_name=arab_name.encode('UTF-8')
```

(if you have arab characters you need UTF-16)

Hope this works :)